# VueJS2 sorting JSON

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a v-for that will go through messages in a JSON response and print them to the screen. The messages come from the server in chronological order, however when I view the data via the Vue chrome add-in the data is be re-ordered alphabetically.

I have a simple example.

Here is the requested JSON via Postman:

```
{
    "e": "e",
    "d": "d",
    "c": "c",
    "b": "b",
    "a": "a"
}
```

Here is the same result when i make the call via Vue and render using v-for:

```
data:Object
a:"a"
b:"b"
c:"c"
d:"d"
e:"e"
```

So the question is, can I stop Vue from re-ordering my data? if not, how should I correctly go about re-ordering it?

Comment: The order of keys in an object is not guaranteed, it's dictated by the iteration method or not at all. It is usually best to not use an object if the sort order is important.

Comment: JSON objects have no specific order and are not guaranteed to keep the order you put things in. I would suggest instead passing an array instead of an object then converting as necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As commenters have noted, order of keys in an object is not guaranteed, so your best option is to have your server emit messages in an ordered structure (like an array).

**If that is not possible**, I have found that key order is *generally* preserved in an object created all at once (like your JSON data). [`Object.keys(data)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), will give you an array of **keys** that is *likely* in the original order.

So instead of something like

```
<div v-for="value in data">
```

do

```
<div v-for="key in Object.keys(data)">
```

and then use `data[key]` to get the value.

You can also try [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) depending on whether you need IE support.

If this is going to be widely deployed, expect it to break for somebody sometime. If you just need something that works for you, this could do it.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Its a real shame there doesn't seem to be a more elegant way of doing this.. Seems its something vue is doing as if i try to do a similar operation with jquery it preserves its order from the server.. anyway thanks again